# How to pause an animation inside a loop without delay

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue with this piece of code:

---

```
    Do While StopProgram = False
        Do Until Count = v
            Application.DoEvents()
            Do While StopProgram = False
                If DirectionNegative = False Then
                    Me.Refresh()
                    Count += 1
                    Angle += 1
                    RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
                    If Angle >= 51 Then
                        Angle = 49
                        DirectionNegative = True
                    End If
                ElseIf DirectionNegative = True Then
                    Me.Refresh()
                    Count += 1
                    Angle -= 1
                    RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
                    If Angle <= -51 Then
                        Angle = -49
                        DirectionNegative = False
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
        Loop
            Count = 0
        Loop
```

---

The problem is that when I press a button on my form, stopping the code (Using the `StopProgram = False`), it will continue until `Count = v` I want to be able to have it where I can stop it inside the loop, I have attempted to do that here but it creates an unexitable loop which ruins the program.

Comment: Do Until StopProgram Or Count = v?

Comment: Why do you need **3** loops? All you need is one loop with an exit condition `If ... Then Exit Do`

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, use a Timer to tick at regular intervals.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Dim WithEvents t as New System.Timers.Timer

sub t_Elapsed Handles....

'your code here. increment/decrement state variables
end sub

Simply disable the timer when you want animation to stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **wrong** approach to your problem, but change:

```
Do While StopProgram = False
    Do Until Count = v
        Application.DoEvents()
        Do While StopProgram = False
```

To:

```
Do While StopProgram = False
    Do Until Count = v
        Do While StopProgram = False
            Application.DoEvents()
```

Comment: This then crashes when the program is stopped due to the code going through the line `Do While StopProgram = False` Then to `Do Until Count = v` Which will keep looping round as it is never satisfied, it then will not do anything.

Comment: ?...the change I made doesn't change the **logic** of your code.  If it gets stuck with this change, then it was getting stuck before.  Moving DoEvents to the inner loop will simply allow the StopProgram variable to be updated by some other event in the application (perhaps a cancel button?)...

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the 2 outer loops.
You will never reach the `Do Until Count = v` part unless `StopProgram` is true anyway. 
You will remain inside the inner `Do While StopProgram = False` loop. You could remove
the inner `Do While StopProgram = False loop` and change 
`Do Until Count = v` to `Do Until Count = v` Or `StopProgram = true`

btw you're setting `Count = 0` when you exit the middle loop so if you need to retain the value of count when StopProgram is set to true you should remove the outer 
`Do While StopProgram = False loop`and the `Count = 0`

```
Do Until Count = v Or StopProgram = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    If DirectionNegative = False Then
        Me.Refresh()
        Count += 1
        Angle += 1
        RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
        If Angle >= 51 Then
            Angle = 49
            DirectionNegative = True
        End If
    ElseIf DirectionNegative = True Then
        Me.Refresh()
        Count += 1
        Angle -= 1
        RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
        If Angle <= -51 Then
            Angle = -49
            DirectionNegative = False
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: This ends up giving me an infinite loop which crashes it completely.

Comment: That's strange.  it's basically the same code with less loops and the Count not being reset.  Could you post the rest of your code or the project files so i can get a better picture of what the programs doing?

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. No need for all those loops.

```
Public Sub Refresh()
  ' ...
End Sub

Public Property Get StopProgram() As Boolean
    StopProgram = ' ...
End Property

Public Property Get Angle as Single
'...
Public Property Let Angle
'...

Public Property Get RadianAngle as Single
    RadianAngle = Angle * PlaceHolder
End Property

Public Sub T()

    Dim Step As Single        
    Step = 1!
    Do
        DoEvents
        Me.Refresh
        If StopProgram Then Exit Do
        If Angle <= 0 Or Angle >= 50 Then
            Step = -Step
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
        Angle = Angle + Step
    Loop

End Sub
```